# Condition as a parameter of a method in ruby

Tags: ruby, parameters, conditional-statements

I am working with a class that is a collection rows containing data. I created a method

```
range#selection!(field, condition)
```

to reduce the contained rows that do not match the condition.

For a while it was enough to provide a regex as condition to eliminate all rows where a field had values not fitting to regex...

Now I would need to compare field values in a mathematical sense <=, >= , more worse I would need to filter fields that contain a date later than a specified date...

```
def selection!(field) {value<=3}
value = 4
if yield then
...
end
```

This is obviously not working but it is what I would somehow need... passing only a condition that I can earliest evaluate when "value" has a vale inside the method. but avoiding to move all the [...] in a block tht I rwrite over and over again

ideas?

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you pass a block to your method and in your method you use `select`/`reject_if` with that block to filter out your collection?